# Cant change the port for jetty

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, jetty

I am running googleappengine on SpringBoot, I want to change the port number from 8080. In springboot docs, you make the change in application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8090,
```

or application.properties `server.port=8090`.

For springboot tomcat, this works, but not for springboot jetty, googleappengine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above property should have worked irrespective of the server.

Give a try with below method (Spring boot 2.0).

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory()
{
    JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.setPort(9000);
    factory.setContextPath("/myapp");
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notfound.html"));
    return factory;
}
```

Refer [configure jetty server spring boot](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/configure-jetty-server/)